# Why char address can't print on screen?

Tags: c++, c++14

When I want to print the address of any `char` variable then, output will be a single `char` or blank.

i.e,

```
char x = 'a';

cout<<&x;
```

output:

```
f
```

Please! tell me why is is happening...?

Comment: This is because there's an overload for this specific pointer type.

Comment: Please suggest me the solution of this.

Comment: Try this: `cout<<static_cast<void*>(&x);`

Comment: Since address doesn't depend on the underlying type, you can cast it to a pointer to any type and print it. I think this should work `(void*)(&x)`

Comment: what is the function of static_cast ?And void * .

Comment: [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast).  `void*` is a pointer that points to any kind object or nullptr (or dangling pointer or wild pointer or uninitialized pointer or garbage pointer), where `void` is used kind of as a wildcard/placeholder in lieu of the type.

Comment: @SachinKadian please [read a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/995714) which explains everything